# NGINX redirect not working for URL

Tags: nginx

We recently moved from a very old Joomla installation to a WordPress version of our website. We are now using NGINX.

There are still a few pages in Google search, that link to the old website such as:

mywebsite.com/online-shop/manufacturer/17-abc?sort=p.price&order=ASC&limit=75

I've tried the following in my NGINX server block:

```
location /online-shop/manufacturer/17-abc?sort=p.price&order=ASC&limit=75  {
return 301 /shop/headsets/pagename/;
}
```

Technically, /online-shop/manufacturer/17-abc?sort=p.price&order=ASC&limit=75 should link to /shop/headsets/pagename/ if clicked.

However, I am still ending up with a 404. The same redirect method DOES work on regular pages, so I am not sure if the special characters in the "old" url have something to do with it.

Some expert help would be appreciated, thank you

PS: Here the current NGINX conf.

```
    server {
        #listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.mywebsite.com;

        location / {
            expires 90d;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            index index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        if ( $cookie_woocommerce_items_in_cart = "1" ){
                set $skip_cache 1;
        }
        if ($request_uri ~* "(/basket.*|/cart.*|/my-account.*|/checkout.*|/addons.*|/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
                set $skip_cache 1;
        }    

        if ($http_cookie ~* "(wordpress_logged_in_|wp\-postpass_|woocommerce_items_in_cart|woocommerce_cart_hash)") {
                set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        if ($http_cookie ~* "(wc_session_cookie_[^=]*=([^%]+)%7C)") {
                set $skip_cache 1;
        }


        location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }


        location /pos  {
        return 301 /point-of-sale/website/vt;
        }


        location /online-shop/manufacturer/17-abc?sort=p.price&order=ASC&limit=75  {
        return 301 /shop/headsets/pagename/;
        }



        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }


    server {
        listen      80;   #listen for all the HTTP requests
        server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
        return      301         https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot



        server_name www.mywebsite.com;
        listen 80;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ServerFault.

There is ways of matching the querystring of an url, but a location block can't match the uri and the querystring at the same time (it only matches the uri).

The question is, do you really need to match "?sort=p.price&order=ASC&limit=75" ? it looks like a way of sorting the page elements, there are much more difficult ways to match both "/online-shop/manufacturer/17-abc" and "?sort=p.price&order=ASC&limit=75" at the same time, but I think the configuration you need is "/online-shop/manufacturer/17-abc" and any querystring that comes behind it doesn't matter (I will change it if you want to match only that uri with only that query_string). This is how I feel you want it to work:

```
location ~ ^/online-shop/manufacturer/17-abc {
    return 301 /shop/headsets/pagename/;
}
```

If you need to match that query string just say it, and I'll write a mapping block for you to read it.